# When querying the Content Service on SDL 8.5, we keep getting "`?' expected but `C' found"

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5, sdl-tridion

When querying a fresh install of SDL 8.5 Content Delivery content service at http://example.com:8081/client/v4/content.svc/Components(ItemId=13,PublicationId=3) we keep getting the following error:

```
<metadata:error>
    <metadata:code>1000</metadata:code><metadata:message>`?' expected but `C' found</metadata:message>
</metadata:error>
```

And this is what we get in the cd_core.log:

```
2018-04-27 11:31:37,999 DEBUG ODataParserImpl - Parsing URI: 
http://example.com:8081/client/v4/content.svc/Components(ItemId=13,PublicationId=3)
2018-04-27 11:31:38,001 DEBUG ODataMessageRouter - Sending error message for exception:
com.sdl.odata.api.parser.ODataUriParseException: `?' expected but `C' found
        at com.sdl.odata.parser.ODataUriParser.parseUri(ODataUriParser.scala:34)
        at com.sdl.odata.parser.ODataParserImpl.parseUri(ODataParserImpl.java:37)
        at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataParserActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataParserActor.scala:34)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
        at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataParserActor.aroundReceive(ODataParserActor.scala:27)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-04-27 11:31:38,001 ERROR ODataRendererActor - Invalid request - com.sdl.odata.api.parser.ODataUriParseException: '`?' expected but `C' found'
com.sdl.odata.api.parser.ODataUriParseException: `?' expected but `C' found
        at com.sdl.odata.parser.ODataUriParser.parseUri(ODataUriParser.scala:34)
        at com.sdl.odata.parser.ODataParserImpl.parseUri(ODataParserImpl.java:37)
        at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataParserActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataParserActor.scala:34)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
        at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataParserActor.aroundReceive(ODataParserActor.scala:27)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The services installed are:
discovery
deployer
deployer-worker
content

All were started with the --auto-register flag and they all registered successfully with the discovery service.
They're running on a UNIX box

---

**UPDATE** Content Svc Config

@Atila Sos

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="8.5" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
<Namespace default="${namespaceprefix:-tcm}"/>
<Global>
    <Storages>
        <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" Id="defaultdb" Type="persistence" dialect="MSSQL">
            <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="10" Type="jdbc"/>
            <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                <Property Name="serverName" Value="123.com"/>
                <Property Name="portNumber" Value="123"/>
                <Property Name="databaseName" Value="BROKER"/>
                <Property Name="user" Value="BrokerUser"/>
                <Property Name="password" Value="tridion"/>
            </DataSource>
        </Storage>
    </Storages>
</Global>
<ItemTypes cached="false" defaultStorageId="defaultdb"/>
<License Location="/cd_licenses.xml"/>
<ConfigRepository CacheEnabled="true" CacheExpirationDuration="600" ClientId="registration" xxx ConnectionTimeout="40000" ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10" ServiceUri="http://123:8282/discovery.svc" TokenServiceUrl="http://123:8282/token.svc">
    <Roles>
        <Role Name="ContentServiceCapability" Url="http://123:8281/content.svc"/>
    </Roles>
</ConfigRepository>
```

Comment: Can you check v2, does it show the same error? Also, can you share the configuration of the Content Service?

Answer (score 3):

Issue looks to have been resolved after updating cd_storage_config.xml file and republishing publication to the broker DB.

Comment: Good one Terry! Can you please also put the details of what was changed. will be easy to find fix in future.

Comment: I wasn't directly involved, but basically the problem was that the expected content wasn't published to the broker DB.  Issue resolved after verifying publishing was successful.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this same issue on a web 9.1 install.  Our issue was that our cd_storage_conf.xml for our deployer and our content service was out of sync.  In the deployer we had our  config publishing some items to the file system and others to the broker.  However, in our content service, we did not have any item types pointing to the file system.  Syncing the two cd_storage_conf files fixed this for us.

Note: while fixing it we also found that the issue could occur if your content service's storage_conf.xml file was malformed in any way.  We ran into this when we incorrectly nested two  tags directly inside each other.

We also saw this issue with XPM enabled if we were reaching out to a non-session enabled content service.  Enabling session preview on the content service fixed this.